# Use contents of a string as a statement

Tags: c#, string

I would like to use the contents of a string as a statement, for example:

```
string exampleString = "exampleStatement";
exampleString.exampleMethod();
```

The use of it in my actual program is below

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url);
SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
reader.Close();

string field = "PublishDate";


foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
{
    data = item.field.ToString();
}

 return data;
```

Is this possible to do?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval#Security_risks

Comment: You could do this with reflection, but it would overcomplicate your code and I doubt you have a good reason to do so.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Although the answers below are, indeed, good answers and will do what you want, I implore you to think about what it is you are trying to do and why you need to do this. Try [Rubber Duck Debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: I want to make a XML parse method where you can put a RSS feed and a field you want in the call and it will return it

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection

```
item.GetType().GetProperty(field).GetValue(item).ToString();
```

(or `GetField()` instead of `GetProperty()` if... that's a field)

Answer (score 1):

This is not trivial like it might be, say, in ecmascript. The simplest option is reflection, for example:

```
data = item.GetType().GetProperty(field).GetValue(item).ToString();
```

however: depending on the API involved, there may be other options available involving indexers, etc. Note that reflection is slower than regular member access - if you are doing this in very high usage, you might need a more optimized implementation. It (reflection) is usually fast enough for light to moderate usage, though.